# laravel 8 blade Dashboard

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

I installed the Laravel 8 and Laravel Breeze starter kit. In the file dashboard.blade.php, I can see `{{ __('Dashboard') }}`, but I cannot understand what that is. I tried to search for `Dashboard` inside the whole Laravel directory, and I didn't find anything.  Then I also tried to change it with `{{ __('Dashboard abcde') }}` and I found that it is just output that text on the web page.

Why does this exist in the template?

Comment: its for translations/localization ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

Comment: It's a very useful thing, but only if you anticipate translating your app into multiple languages. You can skip it if you never intend to do that.

Comment: I don't think so. First of all I repeat that I didn't find `Dashboard` parameter anywhere inside laravel directory. Then language variable syntax is `__('filename.keyname')` and not simple KEYNAME

Comment: well you didn't read the documentation link because the 2nd example uses a different format for the strings ... and "If the specified translation string does not exist, the `__` function will return the translation string key"  ... so that you COULD add translations for this string if you WANT to, its just conveniently setting up the view to use translations, since that is common to serve a site for multiple locales

Comment: Probably you are right, but from that documentation it is not clear how to use translation string `Keyname` syntax. In which file I should put `Dashboard` key if I don't specify filename?

Comment: if you click the 'default translation strings as your translation keys' link in the sentence before that example that would get you to how that is setup with the JSON files ... its just the previous section of the same doc page

Comment: It is not 100% clear. The only thing I can guess is that if I want to use json instead php files for translation, then I need to create just one json file for each lang. And therefore I don't need to use `__('filename.keyname')` syntax. Is that correct?

Comment: you can use both ... if you want the "default translation string" to be the look up key you use the json file  ... if you want to use short names that are the keys to translations you use the php files ... you can use a combination of both, what ever you prefer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226212/discussion-between-schel4ok-and-lagbox). You keep not answering my question

Answer (score 0):

The [following link](https://dev.to/dendihandian/refactoring-blade-views-templates-to-components-2n4d) indicates that it is a constant managed by Laravel Breeze to handle the scaffolding of the user interface.

Inside the app \ View \ Components repository you will find the files to handle the constants in the blade views.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ __('Dashboard') }}` is used for language translation in Laravel applications. You can reference to this Laravel documentation: [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Change it

```
<div class="card-header">{{ __('Change it whatever you Like') }}</div>
```